# C strcpy = Unhandled exception: Access violation writing location 0x00000000

Tags: c, strcpy

I have a problem with strcpy function. Using C.
Main point of this simple code (below) is copying a string from a array to the array of pointers.

```
char string[20] = "ABCDEFGH\0";
char * array_of_pointers[20];

// now I want to copy string to the first available slot;

strcpy(array_of_pointers[0],string);
```

Then strcpy throws me error:

```
Unhandled exception: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
```

Why? I know that this problem is probably simple, but I really don't have a clue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The target buffer has not been initialized.  `array_of_pointers[0]` is just a pointer that (in this case based on the error information from the access violation) points to address 0.  You need to initialize it.  Possibly:

```
array_of_pointers[0] = malloc( strlen( string ) + 1 );
```

`array_of_pointers` is an array of 20 pointers.  Defined like that, each entry in that array must be initialized before it can be used.  Remember too that if you do use `malloc` (or possibly `strdup`) to allocate the memory, use `free` to release the memory.

Comment: I can't do it.
array_of_pointers[0] = malloc( strlen( string ) + 1 );

Visual says: a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned  to a entity of type "char *"

Comment: It sounds like you may be compiling it as a c++ file then.  If that is the case, then you would need to cast it:  `array_of_pointers[0] = (char*)malloc(...)`

Comment: Ok. Case sovled.
I thought definition provided initialization.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize array_of_pointers :

```
array_of_pointers[0] = malloc(strlen(string)+1);
```

Or best:

```
array_of_pointers[0] = strdup(string);
```

Comment: I can't do it. array_of_pointers[0] = malloc( strlen( string ) + 1 ); Visual says: a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to a entity of type "char *"

Comment: The strdup solution will compile. But if you want to call malloc directly you'll need to cast the malloc return value to a ( char * ) . Also as you're now using heap space not stack space remember to check for out of heap space errors.